# How to distinguish leaflet zoom triggered by map.fitBounds from user mousewheel?

Tags: leaflet

I have a map which is refreshed every 30 seconds and on each refresh I fit bounds to the new data. I would like to change the way I fit bounds if a user has manipulated the map, e.g. changed zoom level. My problem is that zoom triggered from `fitBounds` is indistinguishable from user action.

How do I capture/extend `mousewheel` on the map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically there are multiple ways todo same, but you can go with following simple way to distinguish user zoom triggered.

The `onwheel` event occurs when the mouse wheel is rolled up or down over an element.

```js
var map = L.map('map', {
    // Set latitude and longitude of the map center (required)
    center: [12.99766, -84.90838],
    // Set the initial zoom level, values 0-18, where 0 is most zoomed-out (required)
    zoom: 5,
 // scrollWheelZoom: false
});

// Create a Tile Layer and add it to the map
var tiles = new L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.fr/hot/{z}/{x}/{y}.png').addTo(map);


document.getElementById("map").addEventListener("wheel", myFunction);

function myFunction() {
  alert("Mouse wheel Scrolled by user.")
}
```

```css
#map {
  width: 500px;
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.3/dist/leaflet.css" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.3/dist/leaflet.js"></script>


<div id="map"></div>
```

Hope this will helps you.